# Is uninterruptible sleep the only case?

Tags: kill, sleep

French wikipedia say:

> Un processus en sommeil ininterruptible ne peut s'arrêter (ni libérer ses ressources) même lorsque SIGKILL apparaît. 
>   **Il s'agit d'un des rares cas dans lequel un système UNIX doit être redémarré afin de régler un problème logiciel temporaire.**

In english (c/p from old revision of english wikipedia):

> An uninterruptibly sleeping process may not terminate (and free its
>   resources) even when sent SIGKILL.
>
> **This is one of the few cases in which a UNIX system may have to be rebooted to solve a temporary software problem.**

It imply that there is other case than uninterruptible sleep than can need a reboot to solve temporary problem, I thought it was the only one.

What are the other cases?

Comment: it implies there is a nice translation mistake, because `may not terminate` shouldn't be translated by `ne peut s'arrêter` mais par `peux ne pas s'arrêter` it 's subtil but make a huge difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer explains the un-interuptable process and leads to a couple of external articles for more insight. [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223644/what-is-an-uninterruptable-process)

Comment: Please [do not answer with just a link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Since you're citing an answer on Stack Exchange, you can copy it with proper attribution. Except that it doesn't answer *this* question.